# See if 2 columns are 1 to 1 match in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table in sql.
I need to check if columns A and B are 1 to 1 match (Meaning for each row in A, there is only one value in B)
but if you see below, it is not.
Only Cat A and Cat C have one values in Col B.
So is there a way to identify between 2 columns

```
  A      B        C
Cat A   asd       34
Cat A   asd       56
Cat B   dfg       67
Cat B   ghj        7
Cat C   ggh       78
Cat D   ertrty     9
Cat D   tyutyu     6
Cat D   tuuiy     45
```

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT DISTINCT.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT A, COUNT(DISTINCT B)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY A
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B) = 1;
```

Comment: coming from `Only Cat A and Cat C have one values in Col B` it should be a `COUNT(DISTINCT B)`

Comment: I changed my answer, thanks